# Intercept location response to extract a cookie

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, java, cookies

I'm working on a project using nginx as reverse proxy and I'm trying to intercept a response from a specific location in order to extract a cookie and save it in a database.

I'm able to listen a location and verify the validity of a token added as a header. I'm using Java to handle this. SO what I'm trying to do now is to intercept the response and extract a specific cookie. Otherwise extracting only the cookie without intercepting the response.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Maybe a little example of what a request would look like and you are expecting in the response. On the face of it the mirror module might be off help here but it just depends on the detail

Comment: NGINX is not programmable so you can't add custom code into it like that you would have to build your reverse proxy in code the simplest way is PHP & NGNIX and it's still no simple task then you could save it to the DB